# Why getting null pointer exception for driver in testng?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
public class Register extends Base {

    public Register() {
        super();
    }

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {

        driver = initializeBrowserAndOpenApplicationUrl(prop.getProperty("browserName"));
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        homePage.clickOnMyAccountDropMenu();
        homePage.selectRegisterOption();

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifyRegisteringAnAccountWithMandatoryFields() {
        RegisterPage registerPage = new RegisterPage(driver);
        registerPage.enterFirstName(dataProp.getProperty("firstName"));
        registerPage.enterLastName(dataProp.getProperty("lastname"));
        registerPage.enterEmailAddress(Utilities.generateEmailWithTimeStamp());
        registerPage.enterTelephoneNumber(dataProp.getProperty("telephone"));
        registerPage.enterPassword(prop.getProperty("validPassword"));
        registerPage.enterConfirmPassword(prop.getProperty("validPassword"));
        registerPage.selectPrivacyPolicy();
        registerPage.clickOnContinueButton();

        AccountSuccessPage accountSuccessPage= new AccountSuccessPage(driver);
        String actualSuccessHeading = accountSuccessPage.retrieveAccountSuccessPageHeading();
        assertEquals(actualSuccessHeading, dataProp.getProperty("accountSuccessfullyCreatedHeading"),
                "Account Success Page is not displayed");

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifyRegisteringAccountByProvidingAllFields() {
        RegisterPage registerPage = new RegisterPage(driver);
        registerPage.enterFirstName(dataProp.getProperty("firstName"));
        registerPage.enterLastName(dataProp.getProperty("lastname"));
        registerPage.enterEmailAddress(Utilities.generateEmailWithTimeStamp());
        registerPage.enterTelephoneNumber(dataProp.getProperty("telephone"));
        registerPage.enterPassword(prop.getProperty("validPassword"));
        registerPage.enterConfirmPassword(prop.getProperty("validPassword"));
        registerPage.selectYesNewsLetterOption();
        registerPage.selectPrivacyPolicy();
        registerPage.clickOnContinueButton();

        AccountSuccessPage accountSuccessPage= new AccountSuccessPage(driver);
        String actualSuccessHeading = accountSuccessPage.retrieveAccountSuccessPageHeading();
        assertEquals(actualSuccessHeading, dataProp.getProperty("accountSuccessfullyCreatedHeading"),
                "Account Success Page is not displayed");

    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void verifyRegisteringAccountWithExistingeEmailAddress() {

        driver.findElement(By.id("input-firstname")).sendKeys(dataProp.getProperty("firstName"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("input-lastname")).sendKeys(dataProp.getProperty("lastname"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("input-email")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("validEmail"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("input-telephone")).sendKeys(dataProp.getProperty("telephone"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("input-password")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("validPassword"));
        driver.findElement(By.id("input-confirm")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("validPassword"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='newsletter'][@value='1']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("agree")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Continue']")).click();
        String actualWarning = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'alert-dismissible')]")).getText();
        assertTrue(actualWarning.contains(dataProp.getProperty("duplicateEmailWarning")),
                "Warning message regarding duplicate Email Address is not displayed");

    }
```

I am getting this exception java.lang.NullPointerException

I have declared driver in setup code and not written twice still getting this exception

This is my first time using TestNg.Currently i have associated the test case to valid login chrome, but would like to be able to run all 3. Is there a way to associate the 1 test case to those tests or would i have to duplicate the test case per browser

Comment: Where do you have the exception exactly? Show us the stacktrace

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException` : At which line?